# Сохранение положения формы после нажатия на кнопку

Tags: javascript, html

Всем привет, есть такой скриптец:

```js
 var openSerchButton = document.getElementById('hidden_content');
            function onclickOpen() {
                openSerchButton.style.display = (openSerchButton.style.display === 'inline') ? '' : 'inline';
                localStorage.setItem('hide', openSerchButton.style.display); 
            }
            if (localStorage.getItem('hide') === 'inline') { 
                document.getElementById('hidden_content').style.display = 'inline';
            }
```

```html
            <button class="btnCollor btn  btn-md btn-success" 
                    data-toggle="tooltip" 
                    data-placement="right" 
                    title="Натисніть для виклику фільтра" 
                    onclick="onclickOpen()">
                <span>Кнопка</span>
            </button>
        </div>

        <div id="hidden_content" style="display: none; margin-top: 15px;" class="container-fluid " >
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div id="headFiltPan" class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">Зазначте параметри для перегляду даних у разі необхідності</a>
                    </h4>
                </div>

                <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div class="row">
                                <form  class="searchTmi pull-left" style="padding-right: 5px;" method="get" name="frm" action="SearchSki">


                                    <input name="page" id="page" value="1">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="count" id="count" value="0">
                                    <input class="rawOnpage" type="hidden" name="pages" value="${pages}">

                                   
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>
```

Он показывает и прячет форму с поиском по нажатии на соответствующую кнопку, проблема в том что при переходе на следующую страницу, или перезагрузку страницы, нужно заново нажимать на кнопку для того что бы открыть форму с поиском, и так каждый раз, вопрос можно ли как-то сохранять положение формы???

Comment: сохраняйте состояние в `localStorage`

Comment: @MedvedevDev пробую сделать так:  `var openSerchButton = document.getElementById('hidden_content');
            function onclickOpen() {
                openSerchButton.style.display = (openSerchButton.style.display === 'inline') ? '' : 'inline';
                localStorage.setItem('hide', openSerchButton.style.display); // сохраняем значение в ключ hide
            }
            if (localStorage.getItem('hide') === 'inline') { // если значени е ключа hide "inline"
                document.getElementById('hidden_content').style.display = 'inline';
            }` не получается...

Comment: открывает форму, но не закрывает, и после перезагрузки все равно прячет

Comment: Вставьте весь код что у вас есть относительно этого функционала в тело вопроса.

Comment: почему-то оно тут форму не показывает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var openSerchButton = document.getElementById('hidden_content');

openSerchButton.style.display = localStorage.getItem('hide'); // При загрузке страницы смотрим в localStorage и применяем значение

function onclickOpen() {
  var state = openSerchButton.style.display === 'block' ? 'none' : 'block';

  openSerchButton.style.display = state; // Изменяем значение display
  localStorage.setItem('hide', state); // Изменяем значение в localStorage
}
```

P.S. Совет на будущее, именуйте более очевидно.

Comment: Работает, но есть одна проблема, теряется в `div` класс `container-fluid`

Comment: @СергейНиконенко, что значит "теряется"? С классом этот код ничего не делает, только меняет инлайн стили. Предположу, что он как-то иначе начинает выглядеть и опять же предположу, что изначально он `display: block;` а по вашему коду вы его делаете `display: inline;` Если так, то поправил в ответе, если нет, то требуются пояснения.

Comment: да,вы правильно предположили по поводу `display: block;`, спасибо больше